# What is the use case for the "Class" parameter in register_sidebar?

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

I registered a new sidebar and filled in the `class` parameter (see code), I then dropped in an Archive widget and went hunting for my "testing" class. **Not there**.

So what is the class parameter used for. Can I see an example?

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'name'  => __('Footer Widget One', 'wpbs-framework'),
        'id'    => 'footer-01',
        'class' => 'testing',
        'description'   => __('The first footer area', 'wpbs-framework'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="footer-sidebar-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div> <!-- end footer-sidebar-widget -->',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'  => '</h4>'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fill class parameter to [register_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function then the class sidebar-{class name} gets added to the div of that sidebar in the back end.

For example if you register the sidebar using following code :

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'name'  => __('Footer Widget One', 'wpbs-framework'),
        'id'    => 'footer-01',
        'class' => 'testing',
        'description'   => __('The first footer area', 'wpbs-framework'),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="footer-sidebar-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div> <!-- end footer-sidebar-widget -->',
        'before_title'  => '<h4>',
        'after_title'  => '</h4>'
    )
);
```

then in back end you will see the sidebar div having class 'sidebar-testing' as following

```
<div class="widgets-holder-wrap sidebar-testing">
```

Comment: @sleeper You are Welcome. Accept answer if it best answers for your question.

Comment: I just tested that and `sidebar-testing` is **not** in the div. In fact it is nowhere in the code. This is bizarre.

Comment: Have you tested it in back end or in front end?

Comment: Front end. My bad, I see it now (in back end). Sorry. Points coming. Why is this necessary in the backend? That is sorta misleading (to me).